# como ativar o botão direito do mouse para exibir as configurações de câmera no plugin scriptcam?

Tags: flash

Estou utilizando o plugin [scriptcam](http://www.scriptcam.com/) para capturar imagem pela webcam, estou utilizando 2 câmeras e preciso selecionar a câmera quando necessário, o problema é que o botão direito do mouse não ativa as configurações de câmera do flash como especificado em [macromidia](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/br/flashplayer/help/help04.html) linha "**Como exibir este painel novamente?**", alguém sabe me dizer onde faço essa configuração para que quando eu clicar com o botão direito do mouse exiba as opções para eu poder escolher a câmera? isso porque se eu clicar em permitir e lembrar ele não exibe mais a opção de escolha da câmera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O próprio plugin oferece um método para solucionar esse problema:

```
function onWebcamReady(cameraNames,camera,microphoneNames,microphone,volume) {
    $.each(cameraNames, function(index, text) {
        $('#cameraNames').append( $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text) )
    }); 
    $('#cameraNames').val(camera);
}

<select id="cameraNames"></select>

$('#capiture-image').scriptcam({
        onWebcamReady:onWebcamReady,
        path:'/js/scriptcam/'
    });
```